# Description field has no text format

Tags: feeds

The Feed module successfully imports a RSS feed. However the Description field does not display.  I can only see it if I click on "Edit". The problem is that the feed-items do not have a text format.

How can I give the Description field a default text format?

Comment: In Views, I can either set the text processing for Description field for the feed-item to be in plain text - and then see my html tags turned into ugly plain text.  Or I can set it to be full-html and then I see nothing.    How can I import feeds in full-html?

Comment: The node processor has a text format of "full html".   Not sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work properly if I do not use the default feed importer. Instead I created my own feed importer, I think with the exact same settings, and now it imports full html!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work properly if I do not use the default feed importer. Instead I created my own feed importer, I think with the exact same settings, and now it imports full html!

Comment: It also might help to disable the existing feed importer in admin/structure/feeds.

Comment: Could you provide more info please?